# Error in Flux when calculating the gradient due to an in-place operation

Tags: machine-learning, julia, loss-function, flux.jl

I'm diving into `Flux.jl` for my research. My objective is to define a loss function that would measure, so to speak, the convergence of the model towards a uniform data distribution.

I generate `K` random fictitious observations and compare how many of them are smaller than the true data in the training set. In other words, the model generates `K` simulations, and we determine the number of simulations where the generated data is smaller than the actual data. If the model is well trained, this distribution should converge to a uniform distribution.

However, since the resulting histogram is not differentiable, I needed to approximate this idea using compositions of continuous differentiable functions.

```
η = 0.1; num_epochs = 100; n_samples = 1000
optim = Flux.setup(Flux.Adam(η), model)
losses = []
l = CustomLoss(2)
for epoch in 1:num_epochs
    loss, grads = Flux.withgradient(model) do m
        aₖ = zeros(l.K+1)
        for _ in 1:n_samples
            x = rand(Normal(μ, stddev), l.K)
            yₖ = model(x')
            y = target(rand(Normal(μ, stddev)))
           aₖ += generate_aₖ(l, yₖ, y)
        end
        scalar_diff(l, aₖ ./ sum(aₖ))
    end
    Flux.update!(optim, model, grads[1])
    push!(losses, loss)
end
```

So, `generate_aₖ(l, yₖ, y)` would return a vector of size `K+1`, where the element at index `k` is close to `1` if `y` is greater than `k` elements of the vector `yₖ`.

Finally, `scalar_diff` calculates the squared difference between the calculated `aₖ` and the uniform distribution.

However, this code is not functioning correctly, and I am encountering the following issue due to the line `aₖ += generate_aₖ(l, yₖ, y)`,

```
Mutating arrays is not supported -- called copyto!(Vector{Float64}, ...)
This error occurs when you ask Zygote to differentiate operations that change
the elements of arrays in place (e.g. setting values with x .= ...)
```

I'm not sure how to solve this problem. Does anyone have any ideas for a workaround? I need to differentiate it against `aₖ`.